# How fast are nested python generators?

Tags: python, generator

Okay, so I probably shouldn't be worrying about this anyway, but I've got some code that is meant to pass a (possibly very long, possibly very short) list of possibilities through a set of filters and maps and other things, and I want to know if my implementation will perform well.

As an example of the type of thing I want to do, consider this chain of operations:

- get all numbers from 1 to 100
- keep only the even ones
- square each number
- generate all pairs [i, j] with i in the list above and j in [1, 2, 3, 4,5]
- keep only the pairs where i + j > 40

Now, after doing all this nonsense, I want to look through this set of pairs [i, j] for a pair which satisfies a certain condition. Usually, the solution is one of the first entries, in which case I don't even look at any of the others. Sometimes, however, I have to consume the entire list, and I don't find the answer and have to throw an error.

I want to implement my "chain of operations" as a sequence of generators, i.e., each operation iterates through the items generated by the previous generator and "yields" its own output item by item (a la SICP streams). That way, if I never look at the last 300 entries of the output, they don't even get processed. I known that itertools provides things like imap and ifilter for doing many of the types of operations I would want to perform.

My question is: will a series of nested generators be a major performance hit in the cases where I do have to iterate through all possibilities?

Comment: Why not code it up and try? The example you give seems simple enough to code it up both ways.

Comment: Code the alternatives and use the `timeit` module.

Comment: To be clear, "performance hit" versus what alternative implementation? Versus nested loops?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams CPython

Comment: @max versus building a list of numbers 1 to 100, then passing that to an *even* filter, then passing that to a *square* map ... etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried two implementations, one using generators and one without generators. I tested it in 2.7 so `range` returns a list rather than an iterator.

Here is the implementations

Using Generators

```
def foo1():
    data = ((a,b) for a in (i*i for i in xrange(1,101) if i%2) for b in [1,2,3,4,5] if a+b > 40)
    return list(data)
```

Without Generators

```
def foo2():
    result=[]
    for i in range(1,101):
        if i%2:
            i=i*i
            for j in [1,2,3,4,5]:
                if i+j > 40:
                    result+=[(i,j)]
    return result
```

Mixing Both so as not to append a list

```
def foo3():
    data=[(a,b) for a in (i*i for i in range(1,101)) for b in [1,2,3,4,5] if a+b > 40] 
    return data
```

Creating Temporary Lists

```
def foo4():
    data=[(a,b) for a in [i*i for i in range(1,101)] for b in [1,2,3,4,5] if a+b > 40]
    return data
```

Here are my results

```
>>> t1=timeit.Timer("foo1()","from __main__ import foo1")
>>> t2=timeit.Timer("foo2()","from __main__ import foo2")
>>> t3=timeit.Timer("foo3()","from __main__ import foo3")
>>> t4=timeit.Timer("foo4()","from __main__ import foo4")

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
100.95 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
158.90 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t3.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
130.02 usec/pass
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t4.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
133.68 usec/pass
>>>
```

Conclusion:

Generator expressions are powerful and you can optimize it to a much greater extend. As you can see in the example `foo2`, which is the slowest it had the hard time appending a single list which killed the performance. `foo3` and `foo4` has almost the same time so it seems creating a temporary list was not a bottleneck, as it was only created once in the whole iteration. Without generators you would soon end up with some performance issues like appending a list or creating temporary lists. So lazy evaluation came to the picture to give an edge over these performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Difficult to say whether the performance difference comes from using iterators or not.  For example in your loop version you have `for j in [1,2,3,4,5]` in an inner loop.  That creates copies of the same list over and over again and throws them away.

Comment: @wberry It demonstrates a natural python coding style. Maybe you can micro-optimise your non-generator-based python code, but with generators you don't need to.

Comment: @wberry: I was in coherence with that. I definitely should write some conclusion to my test results.

Comment: WHY are generators faster? I've noticed big improvements when using them.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation, using a generator expression is basically equivalent to calling `imap` in that it creates an iterator.  ("[A generator expression yields a **new** generator object.](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression)")  There is no explicit discussion of whether nested expressions create separate (composed) objects or a single expression with complex logic inside, but imagining myself as the interpreter implementer, nested objects seems the most straight-forward way to implement nested generator expressions.

However, there are other factors at play in deciding what will perform better.  I have learned that minimizing the creation of short-lived objects is a big factor in performance, and in Python it's sometimes hard to notice when you're doing that.

Bad performance: `(f(x) for x in range(100))  # builds 100-element list`

Better performance: `(f(x) for x in xrange(100))  # uses counting iterator`

I use `imap`, `ifilter` and `izip` from the `itertools` module all the time in my own implementations and I find that they perform well.  While each invocation of these does create a new iterator object, this is fairly lightweight, sort of like a list that never has more than one item in it.  Besides, in CPython these are implemented in C and are therefore very efficient.

Under the covers, iterators implemented in pure Python have a `next` method that is called to retrieve each datum.  The cost of a method call is not great, but it isn't zero either.  So if your code will be used in a tight loop that must be optimized as much as possible, here are my suggestions:

- Definitely use `imap`, `ifilter` and `izip` where possible as opposed to `map`, `filter` and `zip` which construct lists of the results in memory and return them.  If you have code that uses the list-based versions you will see a big improvement by changing to the iterator-based versions.
- The `itertools` module contains other functions like `takewhile`, `starmap`, `chain` and `chain.from_iterable` that are commonly useful in chained-iterator implementations.
- Rather than chaining multiple applications of `ifilter`, combine the functions passed in where possible.  For example instead of `ifilter(lambda v: v > 0, ifilter(lambda v: v % 3 == 0, data))`, combine the filters as `ifilter(lambda v: (v > 0) and (v % 3 == 0), data)`.  In some cases it may be valid to rearrange the order of operations so that you can collapse them this way.
- When you perform a map operation in order to achieve a side effect, and aren't interested in the results, you can use this instead of `map` to avoid accumulation of the results in memory:

  ```
  def consume(i):
    u'eat all contents of given iterator'
    while True:
      i.next()

  consume(imap(side_effect, data))
  ```

Finally, beware of other gotchas that may increase your memory usage or repeatedly create and destroy objects needlessly, stressing the garbage collector.  This doesn't have anything to do with iterators really but it does affect performance.  The below function creates a lambda expression in memory and throws it away every time it is called:

```
def foo(data):
  return reduce(R, imap(bar, ifilter(lambda v: v % 5 == 0, data)))
```

One way to fix it (this one will still create two iterator objects each time, which is necessary, but not the additional lambda expression):

```
_mod5zero = lambda v: v % 5 == 0
def foo(data):
  return reduce(R, imap(bar, ifilter(_mod5zero, data)))
```

(Note: answer applies to Python 2.  In Python 3 `map`, `filter` and `zip` return iterators.)

Answer (score 1):

"Nested" iterators amount to the composition of the functions that the iterators implement, so in general they pose no particularly novel performance considerations.

Note that because generators are lazy, they also tend to cut down on memory allocation as compared with repeatedly allocating one sequence to transform into another.